# How to downsample an occupancy grid?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an occupancy grid stored in the form of a vector in row-major form. Let's say the cells are referred to by their numbers

```
v = [1, 2, 3, ...... , width * height ]
```

where width and height are the dimensions of the occupancy grid like so

```
0  1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35
```

if we have a 6 x 6 occupancy grid.

What I would now like to do is to downsample the 6 x 6 occupancy grid into a 2 x 2 (or 3 x 3) occupancy grid. The way to do this would be to check the following groups of cells separately:

```
0  1  2 
6  7  8 
12 13 14 

3  4  5
9  10 11
15 16 17

18  19  20
24  25  26
30  31  32

21  22  23
27  28  29
33  34  35
```

and if any cell in a single group is occupied, then the 
new cell in the downsampled grid will also be occupied. Thus, I obtain the following occupancy grid where the occupancy of the cells 1,2,3,4 are determined by the 4 groups of cells above

```
1  2
3  4
```

How can I write the for loop in C++ to accomplish the above for arbitrary sized grids? The only pattern I have managed to figure out is that the index of the first element on every row is i*width where i is the row number

Comment: Can you share some code snippets what you have done so far?

Comment: If you have a sub array larger than `width/2` or `height/2` for example `4 x 4` then would the first row be `0  1  2  3`? Would there also be a grid where the first row is `2  3  4  5`? How does that work? Or is it only 1 `4 x 4` array?

Comment: @ikis I have no idea on how to proceed so I have nothing.

Comment: @Rietty The idea is to downsample as evenly as possible. So all subarrays must fit. I　I understand that if it was a 7 x 7 grid, then obtaining a 3 x 3 with leave out the last row and column which is something I can live with

Comment: @Rietty If the original grid is 6 x 6, then the downsampled must be either 3 x 3 or 2 x 2 since they fit. Not 4 x 4

Comment: @MarcoEmerson Got it just making sure.

Comment: index = y * width + x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing here is probably the 2D to 1D mapping:

```
idx = x + width * y
```

With this, we can then proceed to downsample:

```
input:
    originalOccupancy[]
    originalWidth, originalHeight
    newWidth, newHeight

int downsampleFactorX = originalWidth / newWidth;
int downsampleFactorY = originalHeight / newHeight;

for(int y = 0; y < newHeight; ++y)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < newWidth; ++x)
    {
        int bool occupied = false;
        //now check all the relevant original cells
        for(int oy = 0; oy < downsampleFactorY; ++oy)
        {
            int originalRowStartIdx = (y * downsampleFactorY + oy) * originalWidth + x * downsampleFactorX;
            for(int ox = 0; ox < downsampleFactorX; ++ox)                
                occupied = occupied || originalOccupancy[originalRowStartIdx + ox];
        }
        newOccupancy[x + y * newWidth] = occupied;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to iterate through the original grid and then choose the relevant cells but this answer shows this should be done the opposite way

Comment: You can also do it the other way around. It has the same time complexity, but the memory access pattern differs. So, there might be a performance difference.